# Redshift UNLOAD to S3 using PL/SQL loop variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

Is it possible to use the Redshift UNLOAD command in a stored procedure loop to:

- UNLOAD query dependent on a variable
- Define the S3 path dependent on a variable

I have been experimenting with a contrived example but don't seem to be able to get it to work..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_shoes()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  shoe_record RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR shoe_record IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM shoes' LOOP
    UNLOAD('SELECT * FROM shoes JOIN shoetypes ON shoetypes.shoetype = ''' || shoe_record.shoetype || '''')
    TO 's3://some-bucket/prefix/' || shoe_record.shoetype;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EXECUTE` command to run any string as a command.

So, you can put the `UNLOAD` command into a string (varchar), modify the value of interest and then `EXECUTE` the command.

See: [Supported PL/pgSQL Statements - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html)